# Flyway and cleaning sequences on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, maven-plugin, flyway

I am using Flyway through Maven plugin (v3.0) with SQL Server 2012.

During execution

```
mvn clean compile flyway:clean
```

sequences are not cleaned and when executing

```
mvn clean compile flyway:clean flyway:migrate
```

I am getting the error that sequences already exist!

Is this a bug, or there is some intention in implementing it in this way?

When executing

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'SO';
```

I can see my sequences, despite of executing flyway:clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please file an issue with the exact steps how to reproduce, including a small migration file that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Fixed, details at: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/806. Will try it with 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the workaround until this issue stays unresolved.

At the SQL level, I am checking if a sequence exists. If true, the sequence is dropped and then created again.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sequences WHERE name=N'SEQ_USER_ID')
    DROP SEQUENCE TESTDB.SEQ_USER_ID;
CREATE SEQUENCE TESTDB.SEQ_USER_ID START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20;
```

It is executed correctly with Flyway and it works in my case.